# Access parent ref from child for framer motion useElementScroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have the following 2 components:

**App.tsx**

```
import { useRef, VFC } from "react";

import Card from "./Card";

const App: VFC = () => {
  const scrollRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div ref={scrollRef}>
      <Card scrollRef={scrollRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Card.tsx**

```
import { useElementScroll } from "framer-motion";
import { FC, RefObject } from "react";

interface CardProps {
  scrollRef: RefObject<HTMLElement>;
}

const Card: FC<CardProps> = ({ scrollRef }) => {
  const { scrollY } = useElementScroll(scrollRef);
  console.log(scrollY);
  return null;
};

export default Card;
```

The Card component now throws the following error:

```
ref provided to useScroll must be passed into a HTML element.
```

The only difference between my example and the [example in the Framer Motion docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/##useelementscroll) is I'm getting the ref from the parent component rather than the child. I don't understand the error it's throwing. Can anyone help explain?

Live example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-scroll-ref-p3bqq

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `useElementScroll()` hook inside the parent component where the `scrollRef` element actually exists.

Then, instead of passing `scrollRef` into the child component just pass the necessary value from `useElementScroll()`, which would be `scrollY` in your case.

This worked for me.